# Is it possible to access Mac OSX clipboard data from within a Sublime Text 3 Snippet?

Tags: sublimetext3, pasteboard

For instance, I would like to build a snippet that creates a simple anchor tag in HTML and uses my clipboard data to fill in the href property and the text node of the anchor tag itself.

Here is an example of what that code might look like:

```
<a href="[clipboard_data]">URL: [clipboard_data]</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ST3 natively supports this.

You have two options:
1) Use ST snippets with combination of clipboard data (I use ClipMenu which stores up to 200 past copied items)
2) Write a ST plugin that augments ST snippet system - not sure how hard this would be...